# Why doesn't the JPanel background change colors?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to make the background color of my program white (instead of gray).

I have a frame class that contains the program (a new instance of that frame class is instantiated in the main method). I have the following is the constructor:

```
this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

Just in case it was somehow being blocked out by other panels, I added the same line to the constructor of every panel I have in my program (and I mean every one).

Still, nothing happened.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the code around this call? And by `frame class` do you mean an instance of `JFrame`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that code is called in a JFrame's constructor you are not changing the JFrame's contentPane's color which is what needs to be done. Make that call on the contentPane:

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

The other JPanels added to the GUI shouldn't have their colors set, but should have their opaque property set to false via `myPanel.setOpaque(false);` This will let any image or color behind them to be visible. The exception to this is the contentPane which should always be opaque.

If this doesn't help, you need to tell us more (you need to do this anyway as your question leaves out much necessary and important detail).